# not a subtype of type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, dart

So i tried to call a class, But this error appeared

heres where I tried to call the class

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var appId = prefs.getString('appsId');
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
      .then((_) => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: appId == null ?  new KodeAksesScreen(): new Emailcheck()
      ),
  ));
}
```

and This is the class I called

```
class  Emailcheck {
  Future Emailchecked() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var email = prefs.getString('email');
    runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: email == null ?  new MyApp(): new HSAL()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove runApp from  EmailCheck you already added it in the parent.
runApp is not a widget it is function which Inflate the given widget and attach it to the screen.

Comment: do it like this 

final Emailcheck =new MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: email == null ?  new MyApp(): new HSAL()
      )

Comment: remove the Emailcheck class and  decalre the widget as constant like above do the same for KodeAksesScreen()

Comment: KodeAksesScreen is a Stateful and it only could call a class

Comment: you can create a statefull widget it should have a build function and it should extend StatefulWidget class